# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: pandas

I am trying to change the product name when the period between the expiry date and today is less than 6 months. When I try to add the `color`, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'.
```

`Validade` is the column where the products expiry dates are in. How do I solve it?

```py
epi1 = pd.read_excel('/content/timadatepandasepi.xlsx')
epi2 = epi1.dropna(subset=['Validade'])`
pd.DatetimeIndex(epi2['Validade'])
today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
epi2['ate_vencer'] = (epi2['Validade'] - today) /np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
def add_color(x):
      if 0 <x< epi2['ate_vencer']:
      color='red'
      return f'background = {color}'
epi2.style.applymap(add_color, subset=['Validade'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error means that one can not compare a number with a date and also if the difference between two dates is in months, we again can't compare them e.g., `3` can't be compared with `3 months`.

Comment: Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you in a better way. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data, it seems that you're subtracting two dates and using this result inside your comparison. The problem is likely occurring because df['date1'] - today returns a `pandas.Series` with values of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta`, and this type of object does not allow you to make comparisons with integers. Here's a possible solution:

```py
epi2['ate_vencer'] = (epi2['Validade'] - today).dt.days

# Now you can compare values from `"ate_vencer"` with integers. For example:


def f(x): # Dummy function for demonstration purposes
    return 0 < x < 10

epi2['ate_vencer'].apply(f)  # This works
```

### Example 1

**Here's a similar error to yours, when subtracting dates and calling function `f` without `.dt.days`:**

[image]

---

### Example 2

**Here's the same code but instead using `.dt.days`:**

[image]